# Evaluate if a Userform is modal or modeless in VBA

Tags: vba, userform

Is there a way in VBA (Excel) to determine if a userform's property is modal or modeless?

I thought I could just evaluate the attribute `ShowModal` but apparently `bolFormState = UserForm1.ShowModal` does not work (it puts out an error message on UserForm1.ShowModal `method or data member not found`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following function to your userform

```
Private Function isFormModeless() As Boolean

    On Error GoTo EH

    Me.Show vbModeless
    isFormModeless = True

    Exit Function

EH:
    isFormModeless = False

End Function
```

You can test it with

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    MsgBox "This form is " & IIf(isFormModeless = True, "Modeless", "Modal")
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks you! Took me a while but finally, I tried it out. One question though. What exactly is `Me.Show vbModeless` doing if the form is already open modeless and why is it throwing an exception if the form is opened modal? Thx!

Comment: `Me` refers to the displayed form itselt and in case it is already shown modeless it will redisplay the form. In case you have hidden it before it would reappear. But you could not click on the command button to show the status of the form.. And it throws an exception because an already displayed modal form cannot be re-displayed modeless.

Comment: I'll check if the form is visible as a precondition so I don't have the "reappearing" problem. If it's open in modeless and it "redisplays", do you know what happens in the background? Does it just "stay" open does it for example close and reopen (which it doesn't if I tested correctly). I want to make sure that I don't miss anything like e.g. any events that get called etc.

Comment: PS. Essentially (in this case) I want to switch an open user form from modal to modeless and vice versa depending on it's current state (and it would make a difference in my implementation if for example the hide would get called twice - other events or "background processes" could make similar problems).

Comment: The object userform will just be re-displayed. Nothing else will happen unless you close the object beforehand or use the global default instance of an userform what is not recommended. But the lifetime of the object is in your responsibility.

Comment: Ok, maybe I didn't understand right, I assumed "re-displaying" implies that the form stops being displayed at some point (since usually, the show method will cause the forms visible attribute to change to "true" and trigger all kinds of events etc.). So simply speaking, when I call "Me.Show vbModeless" from within the form (while it's shown modeless) e.g. through a button_click event, virtually nothing happens since it's already visible?!

Comment: Yes if you call `Me.Show vbModeless` from within an already visible form  nothing else will happen. Further reading [Userform – Advanced Notes and Tips](https://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/userforms_advanced_tips.html)

Answer (score 0):

**Simple workaround**

If you only want to ask during userform display (without changing mode) you could profit from the different behaviour of the ShowModal property using a (public) variable in the calling code.

**Explanation:**

As only a modeless call would execute the last assignment `bModal = False` immediately, the `bModal` variable could be asked for during the UserForm instance's run-time

**Example of calling code**

```
Option Explicit
Public bModal

Sub zeigeUF()
Dim info As clsModal
bModal = True           ' provide for default (vbModal or 1)

With New UserForm1
    .Show vbModeless
End With

'if ShowModal property is set to vbModeless (equals False or 0)
'the following assignment gets executed immediately
'and the variable bModal can be asked for in UserForm
bModal = False             ' visible for Userform only in case of modeless display


End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a try, will this already work in the activation event as well?

Comment: Sure you can write above code lines into a `Worksheet_Activate` event :)

Comment: @Albin - could you already give it a try? If helpful, feel free to upvote and to tick the green checkmark of one of the two answers here to accept either the solution of Storax or mine.

Comment: Hi, sorry that it took me a while. Thanks again for your answer. If I understand correctly I have to set the variable every time I open (show) a form (after I use the show command). Wouldn't it be easier just to set a variable before I use the show command which saves the state of the the form (e.g. as a public variable within the form)?

Comment: I'd prefer to leave the responsibility within the calling code `.Show vbModeless` near the explicit (or implicit `.Show` equalling `.Show vbModal`) mode . - ok, you could make `bModal` Public and move the starting `bModal = True` to `UserForm_Initialize()`, maybe together with `Me.Label1 = IIf(bModal, "Modal", "Modeless")` in `UserForm_Activate()`. Maybe not so evident :-)

Comment: Not really sure what you mean. Could you give me an example? Note: in my case I don't create the form during run time and currently I can restrict myself checking for the modal attribute from within the form itself e.g. via a button. But checking the state from within a function/procedure in another module might bit helpfull as well.

Comment: Although, Storax solution seem to be more fitting in this case, I'll be happy to give you an upvote, once I can get your solution to work.